# Adding multiple filtering criteria to a T-SQL query

Tags: t-sql

I need assistance filtering the results of the query below.  Specifically, I need to return only the results where `dbo.pertot_all.sort_method = 2` for all the dates specified in the where clause.  Currently, using what's provided below, it's returning other sort_methods. I am unfamiliar with the order/groupings of the AND/OR operators. Can someone offer some guidance?  Thanks kindly in advance.

```
 SELECT     dbo.SiteDescription.Site, dbo.SiteDescription.Description AS SiteDescription, dbo.SiteDescription.LocationGroup, dbo.chart_all.acct, dbo.pertot_all.sf2, 
                  dbo.SSRS_sf2UnitCodes.sf2description, dbo.pertot_all.sf4, dbo.SSRS_sf4UnitCodes.sf4description, dbo.chart_all.description AS AccountDescription, 
                  dbo.pertot_all.amt, dbo.pertot_all.per_start, dbo.pertot_all.sort_method
 FROM         dbo.SSRS_sf2UnitCodes INNER JOIN
                  dbo.pertot_all ON dbo.SSRS_sf2UnitCodes.sf2UnitCode = dbo.pertot_all.sf2 INNER JOIN
                  dbo.SSRS_sf4UnitCodes ON dbo.pertot_all.sf4 = dbo.SSRS_sf4UnitCodes.sf4UnitCode RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.chart_all LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.SiteDescription ON dbo.chart_all.site_ref = dbo.SiteDescription.Site ON dbo.pertot_all.site_ref = dbo.SiteDescription.Site AND 
                  dbo.pertot_all.sf1 = dbo.chart_all.acct
WHERE     (1 = 1) AND (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000') AND (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.sort_method, 2) = 2) OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-02-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-02-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-03-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-03-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-04-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-04-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-05-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-05-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-06-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-06-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-07-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-07-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-08-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-08-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-09-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-09-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-10-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-10-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-11-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-11-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-12-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-12-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-01-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-01-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-02-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-02-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-03-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-03-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-04-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-04-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-05-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-05-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-06-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-06-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-08-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-08-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-09-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-09-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-10-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-10-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-11-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-11-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-12-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-12-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-02-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-02-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-03-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-03-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-04-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-04-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-05-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-05-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-06-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-06-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-07-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-07-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-08-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-08-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-09-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-09-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-10-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-10-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-11-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-11-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-12-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-12-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2009-12-01 00:00:00.000') = '2009-12-01 00:00:00.000')
```

Comment: Whats up with the `(1 = 1)` filter?

Comment: @Magnus (1 = 1) is helpful when you build WHERE at runtime. You just do not need to check if current statement is first (do not need to add AND/OR) or not (ANR/OR mast be added). It makes no influence on search result and you do not need to write something like `if(where_string != "") where_string+=" AND ";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT     dbo.SiteDescription.Site, dbo.SiteDescription.Description AS SiteDescription, dbo.SiteDescription.LocationGroup, dbo.chart_all.acct, dbo.pertot_all.sf2, 
                  dbo.SSRS_sf2UnitCodes.sf2description, dbo.pertot_all.sf4, dbo.SSRS_sf4UnitCodes.sf4description, dbo.chart_all.description AS AccountDescription, 
                  dbo.pertot_all.amt, dbo.pertot_all.per_start, dbo.pertot_all.sort_method
 FROM         dbo.SSRS_sf2UnitCodes INNER JOIN
                  dbo.pertot_all ON dbo.SSRS_sf2UnitCodes.sf2UnitCode = dbo.pertot_all.sf2 INNER JOIN
                  dbo.SSRS_sf4UnitCodes ON dbo.pertot_all.sf4 = dbo.SSRS_sf4UnitCodes.sf4UnitCode RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.chart_all LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.SiteDescription ON dbo.chart_all.site_ref = dbo.SiteDescription.Site ON dbo.pertot_all.site_ref = dbo.SiteDescription.Site AND 
                  dbo.pertot_all.sf1 = dbo.chart_all.acct
WHERE     (1 = 1) AND ((ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000') AND (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.sort_method, 2) = 2) OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-02-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-02-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-03-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-03-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-04-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-04-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-05-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-05-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-06-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-06-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-07-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-07-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-08-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-08-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-09-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-09-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-10-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-10-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-11-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-11-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-12-01 00:00:00.000') = '2012-12-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-01-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-01-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-02-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-02-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-03-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-03-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-04-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-04-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-05-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-05-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-06-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-06-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-08-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-08-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-09-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-09-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-10-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-10-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-11-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-11-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2011-12-01 00:00:00.000') = '2011-12-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-02-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-02-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-03-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-03-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-04-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-04-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-05-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-05-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-06-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-06-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-07-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-07-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-08-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-08-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-09-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-09-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-10-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-10-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-11-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-11-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2010-12-01 00:00:00.000') = '2010-12-01 00:00:00.000') OR
                  (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2009-12-01 00:00:00.000') = '2009-12-01 00:00:00.000')) AND dbo.pertot_all.sort_method = 2;
```

This should work.

Comment: That will only work for a `sort_method = 2` when the date is `'2012-01-01 00:00:00.000'`.  All other dates will return without regard to the `sort_method`.

Comment: Hm. Sorry. I've missed that `AND (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.sort_method, 2) = 2)`. But @JamesL., I'm afraid you have missed `dbo.pertot_all.sort_method = 2` at the end of query ). Basically, that is not a problem. First condition mentioned in this comment is useless and could be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify the query with an `in` statement.  Consider the following:

```
select 1 where cast('1/1/2000' as datetime) in ('1/1/2000', '1/2/2000')
```

The query will return one row if the `datetime` is in the list.

Your query could be rewritten to something like this:

```
SELECT     fields
  FROM     tables
 WHERE     (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.sort_method, 2) = 2) AND
           (ISNULL(dbo.pertot_all.per_start, '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000') in ('2012-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2012-02-01 00:00:00.000', '2012-03-01 00:00:00.000', etc.))
```

You have to use the `ISNULL()` for the date at least once, so you don't have NULL issues.  But you can compare all the dates using the `in` statement.